Calculate the Hessian of the signed distance function in drake
Since the signed distance queries do not support AutodiffXd, Is this possible to calculate the Hessian of the signed distance function in drake.
I know how to calculate the gradient of signed distance function based on https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/bdcd5ff96a1dfed77791302fb499ec2aa831a03e/multibody/inverse_kinematics/distance_constraint_utilities.cc#L11-L45. I am not sure how to calculate the hessian of SDF.

I am sorry but I don't think we can compute the Hessian in Drake at the moment. I think we will need the gradient of the contact normal, which requires knowing the curvature of the contact geometry. May I ask why you need the Hessian?

BTW, if you need the Hessian of the SDF, one way to (approximately) compute it in described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.09012, which approximates the curvature through randomized smoothing. The authors implemented the approach and released their codebase.

Thanks for your reply. I am try to implement the SCFS algorithm in drake, the algorithm need to calculate the gradient and hessian of SDF. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167691117301469
